# A Database Error Occurred Error Number 1064

Tags: mysql

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups ON groups.id = user_group.group_id WHERE user_group.user_id = '1'' at line 2

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_group 
    INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = user_group.group_id 
WHERE user_group.user_id = '1'
```

Filename: models/Model_groups.php

Line Number: 54

Comment: From the manual GROUPS (Reserved word); added in 8.0.2 (reserved) so it must be wrapped in backticks if you really must use a reserved word as a table or any other name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query raises a number of questions but, sticking to the point, it would be good practice to wrap tables and columns with the `` ` `` character:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `user_group` INNER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id` = `user_group`.`group_id`
 WHERE `user_group`.`user_id` = '1';
```

You could also make this easier to type with aliases:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `user_group` ug INNER JOIN `groups` grp ON grp.`id` = ug.`group_id`
 WHERE ug.`user_id` = '1';
```

The syntax for both of these queries is valid